# I knew how to change a grid cell to a combobox by using wxpython GridCellChoiceEditor，but don't know how to bind for this combobox

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

this is a part of my code.

class AboutRelatedDialog(wx.Dialog):

```
def __init__(self,parent,list1,list2,list3):

    wx.Dialog.__init__(self,parent,-1)

    RelatedGrid = gridlib.Grid(self)

    RelatedGrid.CreateGrid(sum(list2) + 1,5)
    RelatedGrid.SetColLabelSize(1)
    RelatedGrid.SetRowLabelSize(1)

    RelatedGrid.SetCellSize(0,0,1,2)
    RelatedGrid.SetCellAlignment(0,0,wx.ALIGN_CENTRE,wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
    RelatedGrid.SetCellValue(0,0,'label')
    RelatedGrid.SetCellAlignment(0,2,wx.ALIGN_CENTRE,wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
    RelatedGrid.SetCellValue(0,2,'datasource')
    RelatedGrid.SetCellAlignment(0,3,wx.ALIGN_CENTRE,wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
    RelatedGrid.SetCellValue(0,3,'data')
    RelatedGrid.SetCellAlignment(0,4,wx.ALIGN_CENTRE,wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
    RelatedGrid.SetCellValue(0,4,'comment')

    templist1 = ms.ExecQuery('SELECT RepGroup FROM RepGroup')
    templist2 = []
    for i in templist1:
        j = i[0]
        templist2.append(j)

    for index in range(len(list3)):
        RelatedGrid.SetCellAlignment(index + 1,1,wx.ALIGN_CENTRE,wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        RelatedGrid.SetCellValue(index + 1,1,list3[index])
    for i in range(sum(list2) + 1):
        dbsource = gridlib.GridCellChoiceEditor(templist2)
        RelatedGrid.SetCellEditor(i,2,dbsource)
        #RelatedGrid.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE,self.EvtChoice,dbsource)

def EvtChoice(self,event):
    print 1
```

and my code doesn't work,because i don't know how to bind a event for these combobox.
when i choose a datasource,i want to create another combobox to show the data that get from the RepGroup table in another cell.
so i must know how to get the event when i choose a datasoure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't (easily) bind to the events generated by `wxGrid` editor controls, but you can handle `EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGED` events generated by the grid itself whenever a value of one of its cells changes.

Comment: Thank you,it troubles me for a long time!